# non-declaration statement outside function body error in GO

Tags: go

I am a new learner with Go, and these problems confused me a lot. I cannot solve them, could you guys give me a hand?

```
func Solution(A []int, B[]int, K int) int{
.......
res = MaxInt32 
low = 0
high = Min(900, largestId) //largestId is limited here
mid = 0

while(low <= high){
    mid = {low + high} / 2         55
    if(isAvailable(K, mid)){
        res := Min(res, mid)
        high :=mid - 1
    } else{
        low := mid + 1
    }

}
return res                         64
}                                  65
```

The errors show:

```
workspace/src/solution/solution.go:55: syntax error: unexpected =, expecting }
workspace/src/solution/solution.go:64: non-declaration statement outside function body
workspace/src/solution/solution.go:65: syntax error: unexpected }
```

I don't understand why these problems come?

Comment: There is no `while` loop in Go. Change it with `for`.

Comment: yes, I just checked the tutorial and noticed that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "math"
)

func Min(a, b int) int {
    if a > b {
        return b
    }
    return a
}

func isAvailable(k, mid int) bool {
    // ...
    return true
}

func Solution(A []int, B []int, K int) int {
    largestId := 0
    // ...
    res := math.MaxInt32
    low := 0
    high := Min(900, largestId)

    for low <= high {
        mid := (low + high) / 2
        if isAvailable(K, mid) {
            res = Min(res, mid)
            high = mid - 1
        } else {
            low = mid + 1
        }

    }
    return res
}

func main() {}
```

You need to learn basic Go syntax. Take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Because I am a new learner, so there are manys things I do not know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `while` loop in Go. Only `for`. If I do this:

```
package main

func main() {
    var n int
    while (n < 10) {
        n++
    }
    return
}
```

I get the following error (similar to yours):

```
untitled 3:6: syntax error: unexpected ++, expecting }
untitled 3:8: non-declaration statement outside function body
untitled 3:9: syntax error: unexpected }
```

If I do `while n < 10` (no parentheses) I get more precise message, i.e. an *unexpected name* error on line 5 (`while`). I believe due to a bracket usage compiler treats (non-reserved word) `while` as a type (function call or type conversion), but before realising it's non-existent there are other errors to report. Hence, maybe, a confusing message for you.

Unless you have other errors in your code, renaming `while` to `for` should work. And drop the brackets.